# Enforce index hint in mysql update statements Innodb

Tags: java, mysql, sql, innodb, database-administration

I am currently optimizing an application where in we are getting a lot of lock wait time outs. After analyzing the logs using

```
> show engine innodb status
```

we saw undex LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK column that there are a lot of locks being held by update statements. These locks are being held because the indexed column being used by these statements is not unique as per our application. It will help a lot if the update/delete statements can use the desired index which will prevent lock wait time outs.

We are using Mysql 5.7 version and tables are using Innodb engine. There is a way of forcing a select statement to use a particular index but no explicit way of doing it on update/delete as per mysql documentation .

> Index hints apply only to SELECT statements. (They are accepted by
>   the parser for UPDATE statements but are ignored and have no effect.)

To force an index on our update, an approach we have come up with is making optimizer to discard indexes which we do not want by using a function with those columns. Here is a sample query below without any changes :

```
update requests_table set is_active='t' where request_id='1' and is_active='f' ;
```

What we want is index search on request_id but optimizer is using is_active when the application runs .(PS: both columns are indexed and request_id is a primary key here)

Using explain on plain query gives request_id as the chosen index but when the application runs, the optimizer chooses is_active column.

After using functions in where clause, the query formed is:

```
 update requests_table set is_active='t' where request_id='1' and concat(is_active,'')='f' ;
```

Explain query shows request_id as the only possible key to use. This code will be made live tomorrow so i will get the exact stats.

> I want to know if this is a correct approach to force an index use on
>   an update/delete statement.

PS: The question is quiet in detail as this is a very critical issue for us and i didn't want to miss out on any details . Apologies for any mistakes made.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE requests_table`

Comment: How can you see that the Optimizer is using `INDEX(is_active)`?

Comment: Hi i cannot tell you the whole create table code for some reasons . The sufficient info is given in the question . The index chosen by optimizer is also coming in logs.

Comment: If you must redact some of the `CREATE`, that is OK.  But at least show us the columns you have mentioned, all indexes, and engine type.  Which "logs"?